# How to read/show the current mouse pointer coordinates in picturebox when on runtime?

Tags: vb6

when run time, i need add many image On my picture box, i have many image and wish to connect it by picture1.line.
but i need know the actual coordinate on start point to end point(in run time).

Any example or any idea about this how to read/show coordinate of mouse pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VB6 you can do it this way. Create a new form and add the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Type POINTAPI 'Type to hold coordinates
    X As Long
    Y As Long
End Type

'Function that gets current position
Private Declare Sub GetCursorPos Lib "User32" (lpPoint As POINTAPI)

'On mouse move, update form
Private Sub Form_MouseMove(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
    Dim rect As POINTAPI

    'Get position
    GetCursorPos rect

    'Print coordinates
    Me.Cls
    Print "Current X = " & rect.X
    Print "Current Y = " & rect.Y
End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah, Thx u Luke Wage.
Last evening already solved it.Using same method. POINTAPI..